# Is there an SE term for a sudden block down-voting of my questions like this?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that six out of the seven questions I've asked here over a six month period were all suddenly down-voted today.

Is there a formal SE term for this phenomenon?

[image]

My only question not suddenly down-voted in this block is [Is the object in “Eighty-six forty-five.” a proper noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/399555/217285).

**EDIT:** Because my question is closed as duplicate I can't post an additional answer, so I will add this here.

It seems there was *more down voting to be reversed* than mentioned in [the accepted answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10616/217285). On 2017-09-07 an additional `+16` was added to my reputation:

[image]

The original correction:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called **serial downvoting**; a type of voting fraud.

Don't worry. The system will reverse those votes shortly. If it doesn't, you can flag your post for a moderator's attention and request them to investigate the issue.

Read more: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/309993)

**Update**

It appears that the votes are now reversed. See your reputation page. It says

> Voting corrected ([learn more](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed))

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the links, the proper terminology, and the background.  It seems there's still a net -4 (only four reversals of the block of six).  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgVzU.png  Perhaps the SE bots felt that two were well-deserved. Anyway, I'll try to think of more popular (but not populist) questions in the future. :)

Comment: @uhoh Not all downvotes are reversed. Some downvotes were cast for real, because maybe those users thought your post deserved it.

Comment: Please note that it's difficult for moderators to investigate serial downvoting and generally such incidents are referred upwards to staff who have access to voting data. Their investigation can take time: while that is happening, your flag cannot be replied to because a reply will remove the flag which we really want to keep active until we know the result and can reply substantively. There's no way for moderators to say "It's being looked into" -- please trust us that it is.

Comment: They are all "real votes", aren't they? They are all cast by someone pushing the down vote button, either themselves, or via a mean bot. It's just the arbitrary judgement of the SE bots which ones fall within a certain coincidence threshold of time and IP address, and which ones fall outside of it. Anyway I'm not worried about a few residual votes. It is always interesting to learn more about how SE works. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Indeed! See the edit to my question, I've recently had a second adjustment.